# Error in installing OpenCV with python (MAC OSX) and PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, opencv

I want to install the OpenCV to then include it in PyCharm on my Mac, and 
I have started with the terminal following this guideline: [click here](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-opencv-3-for-python-on-mac/)

the problem is when I follow the third step and write this code:

```
$ brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3
```

this error has shown:

```
Error: invalid option: --with-contrib
```

Of course I have installed also the PyCharm IDE for python and the latest verson of python (3.7) to be knowledged

please if you can help me I will appreciate that

**This problem was solved! thank you**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please ask a new question regarding the new error you are experiencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/opencv@3.rb), opencv3 no longer requires these flags.

CMake flags

```
-DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON
-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=#{buildpath}/opencv_contrib/modules
```

enable support for contrib modules.

```
-DBUILD_opencv_python2=ON
-DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON
-DPYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=#{which "python"}
-DPYTHON2_LIBRARY=#{py2_lib}/libpython2.7.dylib
-DPYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=#{py2_prefix}/include/python2.7
-DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=#{which "python3"}
-DPYTHON3_LIBRARY=#{py3_config}/libpython#{py3_version}.dylib
-DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=#{py3_include}
```

provide support for Python3 as well as Python2.

Just run

```
brew install opencv3
```